# Why say « la jouer fine » instead of « le jouer fine »?

Tags: expressions

> Ne confonds pas hâte et précipitation. Il faut **la jouer fine**.

I suppose that this expression translates as "play it careful"? Or more idiomatically in English, we say:

> "There's a fine line between A and B, and we need to **walk that (fine) line**."

But why you need to use « la » rather than « le » is beyond me. This is nothing more than a wild guess, but could it have something to do with « la limite », as in:

> {my interpretation} : **La limite** entre hâte et précipitation est plutôt **fine**. On doit faire attention à ne pas **la** franchir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why say « la jouer fine » instead of « le jouer fine »?

Because the second sentence is incorrect, should be *le jouer fin*.

> Why *la* instead of *le*?

It is not 100% clear what *la* refers to, but this recent set expression has always been using the feminine. As it is something that is played, my first guesses would be either ***la partie***
(sports) or ***la pièce, la scène, la comédie*** (theater).

Here, ***fine*** doesn't means "careful" but ***avec finesse, subtilité***.

After some research, I found in *Le bouquet des expressions imagées* (1990) by Claude Duneton, that ***la*** is stated to probably refer to ***une bille (boule) de billard*** - peut-être de billard électrique, i.e. a ball used to play billiard or maybe pinball. This refers to an expression used in billiard: *[**prendre la bille fine**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/fines)*, i.e. *effleurer* (to kiss), which is the opposite of ***prendre la bille pleine*** (full ball hit). This perfectly matches the current usage of "**la jouer fine**", i.e. instead of frontally attack some task, use **finesse** and tact to achieve it.

Answer (score 5):

« Il faut la jouer fine » means that someone has to act wisely, to be smart.
The « la » isn't used because some idea of limit is implied. You can use that expression in a sentence where the idea of limit isn't present, for instance :

> Mes chances de succès sont faibles, je vais devoir la jouer fine.

« la » and « fine » are refering to the case, [*l'affaire*](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/se-la-jouer-fine-jouer-au-plus-fin.php), which gender is féminin. You could write your sentence this way :

> Ne confonds pas hâte et précipitation. Il faut jouer l'affaire de manière fine.

Comment: Tu pourrais ajouter [cette référence](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/se-la-jouer-fine-jouer-au-plus-fin.php) pour appuyer ta réponse, en effet ce qui est important c'est de souligner, comme tu le fais dans ta réponse, que *fin* a le sens d'habile.